# permute the values ​of a dataframe diagonally

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table, transpose

How can i transform the dataframe *data* into *new_data* ? I used *pivot_longer* and *pivot_wider* but i don't get what I want.

```r
data <- data.frame(
  ind = c("la", "lb", "lc"),
  c1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  c2 = c(4, 5, 6),
  c3 = c(7, 8, 9),
  c4 = c(10, 11, 12)
)
```

#### Desired result

```r
new_data <- data.frame(
  ind = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"),
  la = c(1, 4, 7, 10),
  lb = c(2, 5, 8, 11),
  lc = c(3, 6, 9, 12)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `R base`

As far as I know, there is no `t()`-like function for data frames in base `R`. An `R-base` approach:

```
x <- t(as.matrix(data))
colnames(x) <- x[1L, ]
x <- x[-1L, ]
x <- as.data.frame(cbind("ind" = rownames(x), x))
rownames(x) <- seq(nrow(x))
x
```

wrapped in a small function:

```
transpose_df <- \(df) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(df))
  x <- t(as.matrix(df))
  colnames(x) <- x[1, ]
  x <- x[-1, ]
  x <- as.data.frame(cbind("ind" = rownames(x), x))
  rownames(x) <- seq(nrow(x))
  x
}
```

gives

```
data <- data.frame(
  ind = c("la", "lb", "lc"),
  c1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  c2 = c(4, 5, 6),
  c3 = c(7, 8, 9),
  c4 = c(10, 11, 12)
)

transpose_df(data)
  ind la lb lc
1  c1  1  2  3
2  c2  4  5  6
3  c3  7  8  9
4  c4 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 4):

#### `data.table::transpose`

```r
data.table::transpose(data, make.names = "ind", keep.names = "ind")

#   ind la lb lc
# 1  c1  1  2  3
# 2  c2  4  5  6
# 3  c3  7  8  9
# 4  c4 10 11 12
```

#### `sjmisc::rotate_df`:

```r
sjmisc::rotate_df(data, cn = TRUE, rn = "ind")
```

---

#### `tidyverse`'s `pivot`s:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  pivot_longer(-ind) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "ind") %>%
  rename("ind" = name)

#   ind la lb lc
# 1  c1  1  2  3
# 2  c2  4  5  6
# 3  c3  7  8  9
# 4  c4 10 11 12
```

Comment: Never heard of `sjmisc::rotate_df()` (+1). Thank's for letting us know.